# Relative reference in the response header in Restlet

Tags: relative-path, restlet, response-headers

Is there a trick to bypass forced relative reference resolution when setting Location field in the response header in Restlet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build explicitly build an absolute URL this way in a server resource for example:

```
@Post
public void addElement(Element element) {
    Element addedElement = (...)
    setLocationRef(getRootRef()
          + "/elements/" + element.getId());
    setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_CREATED);
}
```

Comment: Right, but this still forces me to pass an absolute reference in the response header. The intent is to pass a relative reference and let the client worry about resolving it.

Comment: RFC7231, which obsoletes RFC2616, allows Location to have the form of a relative reference (section 7.1.2). Does Restlet implementation allow to override the default behavior of relative reference resolution? Is there perhaps a way to build the header manually?

Thank you Thierry for your reply!